Drools 9 Spring 3 using RuleUnit unable to load rules from file system
I am trying to upgrade Drools to version 9.44 from 7. My application is running on SpringBoot 3. I implemented RuleUnit and migrated all the rules to the new format. According to the specs the DRL files should be located at the directory matching RuleUnit package name. I migrated all the rules to the resources folder with the recommended directory structure. When I run my local SpringBoot unit test everything works, the rules are loaded properly. But when I deploy and run my application on the cluster, I see this error message:
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: begin 5, end 3, length 97\\n\\tat java.base/java.lang.String.checkBoundsBeginEnd(String.java:4606)\\n\\tat java.base/java.lang.String.substring(String.java:2709)\\n\\tat org.drools.ruleunits.impl.RuleUnitProviderImpl.collectResourcesInJar(RuleUnitProviderImpl.java:189)

This tells me that KIE container is trying to load the rules from JAR instead of file system.
I am not sure how to change it so the rules are loaded from the specific folder in the file system. Please help.

Remember that src/main/resources is packaged inside the jar, with the values available on the classpath. (which is why you use relative paths to reference these files and not absolute paths.)

I didn't find anywhere in the docs how to properly load DRL files from the file system. It just says that these files should be located in the directory matching RuleUnit class package. This way they got packaged in the jar, which I am trying to avoid in order to be able to dynamically change them if needed.
